# ffmpeg - how to pan left on an image

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a command that works well to pan right on an image:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loop 1 -i image0.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=ih:ih:iw/2*t/20:0,trim=duration=5,scale=-2:720" -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

but I can't find what would be the equivalent to pan right. I tried something like this

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loop 1 -i image0.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=ih:ih:iw/2-t*20:0,trim=duration=5,scale=-2:720" -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

but it's not giving good results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loop 1 -i image0.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=ih:ih:iw-ih-(iw-ih)*t/20:0,trim=duration=5,scale=-2:720" -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

You have to set an initial offset, mine is `iw-ih` and then subtract an argument which expresses movement in time, here `(iw-ih)*t/20`

Comment: thanks, there is quite a jiggle on the output video though, any idea how to remove it? (I think the jiggle is also on the pan to right effect, but its intensity seems to vary depending on the input image)

Comment: Scale up 10x before crop, and scale down after crop.

Comment: How to crop to correct ratio? It works, but I got 720x720 image, and while set scale=1280x720 I got stretched image.